# How do I get an array of all pixel coordinates for a given text

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, text, pixel

To animate a text in a similiar way like [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/04/particle-trail-animation-javascript/), I need to get all the pixels of a given text. I need the pixels to start animating from left to right along all letters of the word.

So my question: Is there a way to write a function that takes a font and a string and returns an array of pixel coordinates.

I have tried to 'draw' my own pixels and use the coordinates, but it doesnt look very good and authentic. I have also looked for equations that look like letters to use.

I am trying to do this in an Ionic Angular App, so I can't use Canvas.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for position of a Dom element relative to the browser window such as in this SO qn - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element-relative-to-the-browser-window ?

Comment: No, Im looking for a way to get all pixels of a string so I can draw the text in the DOM

Comment: Canvas was my first guess. I don't think it is possible without guess without using server technology

Comment: It's a static text so I could generate the pixels in a different language, but which one should I use to do that?

Comment: As you say it is a static text, can't you still use Canvas in a different app to get your pixels ?

Comment: Why not use an SVG and animate it's path?

Comment: I am doind this same thing but using canvas... if anyone has the indexes positions for the letters it would help me